# Why do my images shrink after loading with glide library

Tags: android, gridview, android-glide

Hi I'm populating a gridview with glide image loader library when they first get called into my fragment they look like this [image: perfect]
But after scrolling up and down they are resized and look like this [image: too small]
Is this something I'm doing with my gridview, the glide library, or is it something else like my placeholder image? on the second screenshot If I press on an image it lights up to show it is in actual fact filling that whole space, anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I've tried changing the call in glide playing with centercrop and such but it seems to make no difference, I'm not sure how I would work out the width and height of each cell, any suggestions welcome

EDIT
 here is how im calling glide

```
   Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(mThumbIds[position])
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
                .centerCrop()
                .override(500,300)
                .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Can I know whether your orginal image is square(as first screen) or as rectangle (as in second screen). Most probably your image will be a rectangle one as shown in figure 2 itself. the first one will be the stretched formate as you are not using glide.

Comment: @Niv the images are all rectangular, and are populated from photobucket urls, ive edited my question to include the way im calling glide

Comment: are you getting it correct now? if not remove that .override(500,300) notation or make it .override(500,500)

Comment: yeah 500,500 comes out too small have gone for 700 700 and it looks perfect, so this is the right dimensions just trying it on a smaller device to check for consistency, but if youd like to add your comment as an answer ill accept it.

Comment: edited my answer please have a look

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually you have to give fix width and height to your image container(ImageView).

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/channelImage"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sama" />
```

Then when you call glide you have to override your width and height dynamically with override method. This is maximum Width and height for you container.

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .load("your url")

                    .placeholder(R.drawable.tv2v_icon)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .override(500,500)
                    .into(channelImage);
```

hope this can help you.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I had the same problem on resuming an activity with images

Answer (score 7):

**Following helped me:**

1) Used adjustViewBounds = "true" in your Image View -> This will make the image view maintain its aspect ratio according to its image when it draws/redraws/resizes

2) Set layout_width = match_parent and layout_height = wrap_content for the recycler view's item view xml, and also for the Image View.

**Reason:**

Suppose Recycler view is set up with Grid Layout Manager having 2 columns in vertical orientation
It will force the recycler view's item row's xml to be of half the screen width.
Due to value of match_parent in the item row's and its chid's (imageview) layout_height attribute, it will result in image become half the screen's width.
Now, due to adjustViewBounds = true, the image view would itself adjust its height to maintain the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 6):

Use **.dontAnimate()**  method to solve the issue.

```
Glide.with(context)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(pathReference)
                .dontAnimate()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
                .into(holder.logo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyway there are methods like .fitCenter() or .centerCrop() .Try using this methods in

```
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load("")
                            .centerCrop()
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .crossFade()
.override(1000,1000)
                            .into(myImageView); 
           .
```

Comment: Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .load(mThumbIds[position])
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .override(500,300)
                    .into(imageView);
 is how im calling it at the moment have tried removing the override method

Comment: sorry i had tried 500 and have now also tried 700 and 1000, but no joy the 500 looks perfect on my LG g3 (5.5" screen) but it adds a huge amount of spacing between images on top and bottom but left and right fit fine on my htc 610 (4" screen)

Comment: try fit xy in your adapter image view

Comment: anyway the reason behind this is that your image is rectangle. if you make it square to your desired proportion it will be all right.

Comment: That can't be the answer, the images have to be rectangular

Answer (score 1):

For an almost identical problem **all I had to do was add .override(*maxItemWidth*, *maxItemHeight*)**.  This seemed to prevent whatever Glide was doing that caused the images to shrink.

Note: *maxItemWidth / maxItemHeight* are the values I used for the recycler view item container, but the ImageView that holds the image is actually smaller (because of a border and label).

```
    Glide
        .with(context)
        .load(categoryItem.getThumbnail())
        .asBitmap()
        .fitCenter()
        .override(itemWidth, itemHeight)
        .into(holder.imgIcon);
```

Here is my xml if curious:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@id/item_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:padding="4dp">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_rectangle"
        android:padding="2dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works in version Glide V4 (4.8.0)

import 'Glide' in gradle (Currently, the newest version is 4.8.0):

```
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

your ImageView in RecycleView item should look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and in your adapter:

```
        final Content content = getItem(position);
        ImageViewHolder viewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) holder;

        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
        options.optionalFitCenter();

        Glide.with(Application_News16.getAppContext())
                .load(content.getValue())
                .apply(options)
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.img_loading_s)
                        .error(R.drawable.img_error_s))
                .into(viewHolder.image);
```

Answer (score -1):

Overriding for rectangular images could lead the image not correctly displayed when height is sometimes greater and width some time else.

Here is what I did, just in case someone wants to explore. This fixed the Glide bug of shrinking the images when the RecyclerView is scrolled up and down.

FYI: I am using androidx instead of the support libraries, but it should work with ImageView and AppCompatImageView widgets as well.

Here is the snippet from the RecyclerView's Item Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout...
       <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
           android:id="@+id/attachment_image"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:background="@drawable/camera_image_preview_default"
           android:minWidth="400dp"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Here is the Code in my adapter onBindViewHolder override:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ....
    ....
    attachmentImage.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(AppGlobals.IMAGES_THUMBNAIL_STORE_PATH + packet.getImageFileName())))
        .placeholder(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image_loading_placeholder, null))
        .centerCrop()
        .error(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.missing_thumbnail, null))
        .into(attachmentImage);
    ....
    ....
}
```

If you notice,

1. Before the Glide binding, the ImageView has been set to layout 0, 0, 0, 0. This will ensure Glide interprets it as a new layout inflation and not use Cache Strategy.
2. The `minWidth` has been set to `400dp`, while the `layout_width` has been set to `match_parent` and `layout_height` has been set to `wrap_content`. You can manipulate the `minWidth` to your choice of limit.
3. The binding will use `centerCrop()` at runtime so it doesn't really matter what `scaleType` you set at design time in the xml layout.

FYI: This example uses loading an image from the local device's public external storage directory. use other implementations to load from network or  URL

Credits: The setting of layout to all zeros was mentioned and recommended by TWiStErRob in the Glide Github Community Forum.

@ https://github.com/TWiStErRob

For the issue #1591

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1591

On a side note, if you set the ImageView in the xml layout with absolute `layout_height` and `layout_width` - say 400dp and 300dp respectively, Glide works perfectly. Its only when the sizes are different for every image, one sees the problem.